# Does hamburger menu follow iOS design guidelines?

Tags: ios

I have done a research about settings page and I found this link in the Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/settings/

I've always thought that hamburger menu doesn't follow iOS design guidelines, but after watching official documentation, I have doubts.

Could I consider it correct according to that for the whole app or just for Settings flow?

Also I had a look to this link https://uxplanet.org/tab-bars-are-the-new-hamburger-menus-9138891e98f4 where we can see that burger menu is not "good" practice for iOS

Comment: There is a WWDC talk about navigation that uses the hamburger menu as a way of highlighting a bad navigation pattern.

Comment: Could you add the link?

Comment: I will try to find it yep.

Comment: It was from wwdc 2014 by Mike Stern. I can only find transcripts of it now but if you google “wwdc 2014 mike stern” you can search for it.

Answer (score 2):

Now that SF Symbols has the hamburger icon, I would say it is officially approved by Apple.

Comment: SFSymbols now have it under the name "line.3.horizontal"

Answer (score 1):

When you submit an app to the AppStore with that kind of design Apple can let it go through (there's a lot of apps in the AppStore that use that menu, especially cross-platform apps) but have you ever seen an app designed by Apple where you can find such thing? I have an iPad and an iPhone and I never saw that menu, so yes, it's not a good practice, it's an Android thing...

Comment: It’s not even and Android thing. It’s just bad.  it came initially from apps like Facebook where they needed a dumping ground of unused features.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. The point here is the link from Apple that I attached to the question. It shows burger menu. I've never use it and I won't use it, but I saw that and I had doubts about this concept

Comment: @Fogmeister Yep, I agree, it's bad, really bad, I hate it! But I think it's an Android thing because you can find it in apps developed by Google. If I remember correctly you can find it in their Store, Google Play!

Comment: @Blue1905 just curious, but why is it unanimously really bad?

Comment: @AlanS, it's just an opinion! I'm an Apple fan to be honest and I like the way they make things easier and more simple and I think that menu makes the view complicated somehow, there's a lot of stuff in one view! it's ugly for me.

Comment: @Blue1905 fair enough, was just comfused cause in the OP one of the comments said that it is an example of bad navigation patterns, so that threw me off a bit haha